# How do I read a tab delimited string (with spaces) into variables correctly ?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to read a tab-delimited line (which also has white spaces) into variables using a bash script. The problem I encounter is trying being unable to read tokens with spaces correctly. I tried setting IFS='\t' but it doesn't work.

Here's the code I tried -

```
IFS='\t'
while read -r var1 var2 ;
do 
       echo "$var1"
       echo "$var2"
done < cat sample.txt
```

Sample.txt contents :

```
 variable1  This is variable2
```

Expected Output :

```
 var1 = variable1
 var2 = This is variable2
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `IFS=$'\t'` to make it work.

`bash` don't interpret escape sequences in string literals. `$'somestring'` is a syntax for string literals with escape sequences. So unlike `'\t'`, `$'\t'` actually is a tab.

> From `man bash`:
>
> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially.  The word expands
>   to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by
>   the ANSI C standard.

Also, you do not need `< cat file`.

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=$'\t' read -r var1 var2      
do
       echo "$var1"
       echo "$var2"
done < sample.txt
```